# What does a TV receiver circuit look like?

Tags: radio, receiver, video, tv, video-transmitter

I found a few circuits for TV transmitters, but no receivers.

I've looked at other simpler RF transmitters and receiver, but it's not obvious to me how to reverse the circuit that I have.

I want to send an expendable RC car into a collapsed tunnel, cable wouldn't work it's a labyrinth.

[image]

Can you give me an example of a vhf receiver and help me understand how it works?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. These questions require a broad scope of answers, many of which will be opinions. Pardon me saying so, but I think you are in a bit over your head. Prove you understand the details of what is required and we will help.

Comment: "Expandable" or do you mean *expendable*?

Comment: Expendable don't shoot me, please? Yes I'm a beginner and don't have the necessary knowledge. For a long time I wanted to use a pic32,wifi and a digital camera for this project, that's how lost I am.

Comment: @Wtom193 Don't stress.  We are just giving the best advice we are able.  We want to be sure of what you're asking before we put a lot of effort into a really good answer and we want the questions to be helpful for everyone who comes searching for them.  Also, the better your question is, the better the chance someone will really put their heart into an answer.

Comment: You wouldn't do this (at least not legally) with a broadcast TV transmitter.  There are video links commonly used for RC hobby applications (WiFi is also used but laggy) however your description of the environment sounds like one which wants a wire/fiber tether

Comment: Are you willing to capture an image, digitize it, transmit the bits over a carrier frequency that penetrates dirt and rock and water, slowly (over 1 to 100 seconds) gather up the bits on the surface, and examine the image to decide which direction to proceed?

Comment: @ChrisStratton In my country you can use a maximum of 2W rf if it doesn't interfere with some device owned by someone else.

Comment: @KH  Thx, I want to receive my analog camera wirelessly on a portable device preferably on a laptop or tablet or raspberry pi. I'm happy with the transmitter, but I don't know what to do on the receiving side I thought I could also easily find a receiver circuit as well than use an RCA to usb dongle. analogsystemsrf I don't think it has to penetrate only bounce in the tunnel. This is an old winery cellar that has still stuff in it I just want to know what's in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your linked transmitter is very elementary. But if there's an analog composite video signal feeded to connector "Video input" with right amplitude and the potentiometer is well adjusted, a normal analog TV-receiver can really catch and show the video.

The reverse circuit -  a receiver which outputs analog video can in theory be a simple superregenerative AM receiver, because your transmitter makes AM, not vestigial sideband modulation signal like proper norm respecting TV transmitters. Unfortunately video display equipment need strictly controlled video signal voltage for acceptable image and no simple receiver will provide it. That's why you actually need a proper analog TV receiver.

ADD: I just realized that you want to send signals through soil and rock. It is probably impossible except by using very low frequency which would need huge antennas. The water in the soil will attenuate VHF and UHF range signals to non-detectable very soon. You should do some tests before continuing the project.

Comment: I see thanks! Do you think sg like RTL2832U usb dongle would work? I want the receiver to be portable maybe a laptop or tablet with otg or raspberry pi.

Comment: @Wtom193 RTL2832U is a receiver for modern digitally coded TV signals, you need a NTSC or PAL receiver. Your transmitter is for NTSC and PAL analog video signals. If you do not know those legacy analog TV systems, you need some local help.

Comment: https://www.rtl-sdr.com/analogue-tv-with-rtl-sdr/   I found this so I guess it would be a start. I think the signal would bounce in the tunnel.

Comment: @Wtom193       Your software radio link presents a complex project itself. Get an old TV receiver from analog television broadcast era. Start by testing that bouncing. It is theoretically possible if the wavelength is shorter than double diameter of the tunnel. Due the irregular bouncing route and unpredictable position of the transmitting antenna prepare to use circular polarization and diversity receiver. I bet digital signals would be more flexible because you can reduce data rate in case of weak signal and get sharp images. Analog TV needs much more powerful signal.

Comment: It's only need tvsharp or am I missing something? I can't find any analog tv receiver on a reasonable price. Yes but digitalizing the camera output would not be that easy, I know use a digital camera but it needs synchronization that is where I was stuck and give up.

Comment: @Wtom193 I haven't tried SDR dongles. I bet you need also some bandpass filter to remove spurious responses caused by non-ideal rf-circuits and strong existing signals at other frequencies. In addition you surely need low noise amp in front of the SDR dongle. I'm afraid that with simple whip antennas and transmitting power well below one milliwatt your max good image distance will be about 20 meters and that's in free air. Old TV: Have you checked second hand shops and surplus gear piles of your friends and their parents especially? People who are now older than 50 yrs can well have one.

Comment: Someone contacted me with a transmitter receiver pair, I maybe going to experiment with SDR(that I already wanted to use in future other projects). I do have and old tv with antenna, but it's the only one that can receive rf these were not popular in my area and I also don't want to disassamble it and I can't use it on the spot(no electricity). Thanks I accepted your answer I have a few options now.

Comment: @Wtom193 OK. But I still suggest an old TV as test equipment. See, can you get any signal detected in those cave conditions.